# Почему возникает такая ошибка и как с ней справится?

Tags: python, pyautogui

Вот мой код:

```
import pyautogui as pg

pg.move(200, 300, 0.5)
```

Он вызывает такую ошибку:

```
partially initialized module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'move' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Стас, спасибо вам большое!!!

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, пометьте его как принятый, тем самым вы отблагодарите ответившего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта ошибка переводится

> как частично инициализированный модуль 'pyautogui' не имеет атрибута
>   'move' (скорее всего, из-за циклического импорта)

Она возникает если ваша программа названа по имени модуля, который вы импортируете. Python пытается вместо настоящего модуля использовать вашу программу, и появляется ошибка. Исправляется очень просто - переименуйте свою программу и ошибка пропадёт.